# How to publish an event in ActiveMQ on row level changes in DB2?

Tags: db2, activemq-classic

I don't know if it's possible or not, and I Googled it I didn't find any concrete solution for this.

I have a scenario to implement where I need to use the pub/sub model to understand what changes are made on certain DB2 tables. So if the user updates or adds any data in certain tables then the event should be published on MQ along with data and metadata.

Any guidance or suggestions would be helpful on where to start.

Comment: Are you able to change the client that inserts the data into the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially create a [SQL trigger](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000931.html) that runs a [Java stored procedure](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=java-stored-procedures-user-defined-functions) to send a message to a JMS topic in ActiveMQ for the table's you're concerned about.

You could also potentially change the client that is modifying the database so that it sends a message to a JMS topic in ActiveMQ when it does the database work. Ideally this would be in an XA transaction to ensure the actions are atomic.